# rxjs buffer based on predicate

Tags: rxjs, observable, buffer

I want to do something that I *think* should be pretty simple, but the correct rxjs operators are eluding me.

I want to buffer an observable of strings, flushing the buffer when the observable produces a matching string. Something like this:

`obs.pipe(magicBuffer(x => x === 'matching string'))`

...to produce an observable of arrays of strings.

All of the buffer operators I can find seem to buffer based on second observable, not the original source.

Comment: If I have to write an operator, I will. It would be pretty simple to write. But I rather instead use the canonical approach for this problem if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `multicast` to split the source Observable and then just `buffer` until it emits the matching string.

This will split the source emissions by `'x'` character.

```
import { of, Subject } from 'rxjs'; 
import { filter, buffer, multicast } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = of('a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'd', 'x', 'e' , 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'x', 'l', 'm');

source.pipe(
  multicast(
    () => new Subject(),
    s => s.pipe(
      filter(v => v !== 'x'),
      buffer(s.pipe(filter(v => v === 'x'))),
    )
  )
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jad7ez